# Reduce number of arguments of a function in R

Tags: r, function

I'm wondering whether there exists an elegant way in R to reduce the number of arguments in a (mathematical) function. For example, suppose that I have a function

```
f1 = function(x, a) {x^2 + a},
```

and suppose that I would like to update this function with a specific value of `a`. How can I get a new function that only depends on `x`? Something like this (pseudo-code):

```
f2 = function(x) f1(x, a = concrete value)
```

How can this be done in R? I'm fairly new to R programming and couldn't find the answer elsewhere.

Comment: It can be done exaclty as you described. For instance, if `a` should be set to `2` you could use  `f2 = function(x) f1(x, a = 2)`.

Answer (score 2):

You can.  Here is a straightforward method

```
f1 <- function(x, a) x^2 + a

f2 <- function(x) f1(x, 2)
```

Then as an example,

```
f1(4, 2)
[1] 18
```

returns the same value as

```
f2(4)
[1] 18
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are after is called "Partial application" in some functional programming languages. There are several implementation of that for R. Here are a few:

#### functional library

```
library(functional)
f2 <- Curry(f1, a=2)

> f2(10)
[1] 102
```

#### pryr library

```
library(pryr)
f2 <- partial(f1, a=2)

> f2(10)
[1] 102
```